# Is there any difference in meaning between "blow someone off" and "cancel on someone" in the sense of canceling plans with someone?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between *blow someone off* and **cancel on someone** in the sense of canceling plans with someone? For example:

> I made a date with Monica for coffee, but she **canceled on** me.
>
> I made a date with Monica for coffee, but she **blew** me **off**.

Comment: Same meaning but the second is limited to verbal slang or very informal messaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrases overlap, but using "blew me off" indicates that the speaker feels they have been treated with contempt. The first version is softer, though saying "canceled **on me**" also indicates that one feels ill-treated. A more neutral expression would be simply "...she canceled."